# How can I get only the time range from the given figure in firebase realtime database using Flutter?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter

[image]

As you all can see in the above picture, I want to access only the time range that is '9:00 - 10:00' from firebase real-time db. My question is how can I do that? I am using flutter here.
I am getting both time range and expert id.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase realtime database returns result as Map<String,dynamic>. So to access `9:00-10:00` you can use in the similar way as in jsons like:

```
result["session"]["29-09-2021"]["9:00-10:00"]
```